# Can Amazon SES process email without any real email address behind it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I have a domain registered to me and its set up in Route53 on aws.
Is there a way that SES can process emails sent to a non real address (pinkopalino@mydomain.com)?
e.x
add processing rule to SES to save email on S3 just based on the fact the domain is mine an configured on AWS or do I need a real email server (gmail etc) to have a real email behind it for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

OK its possible.
Its enough to verify the domain and SES DKIM and MX in aws route53 for the domain and the SES rule will process the emails.